# Excluir elemento de um array

Tags: c#, array

Preciso excluir o primeiro elemento de um array.

Tenho: `Numero[10]`.

Como faço para excluir o valor em `Numero[0]` e sobrescrever os outros elementos?

Comment: O que seria "subscrever os outros elementos"?

Comment: uma sugestão seria utilizar Filas, (Queue)

Comment: É necessário usar Array mesmo? Você poderia usar uma List e depois o método `List.Remove`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Preciso excluir o primeiro elemento de um array

Não é possível excluir uma posição ou elemento de um array. Se o array tem 10 posições, ele sempre terá 10 posições.

Utilize o método `Clear()` da classe `Array` para **redefinir essa posição do array para o valor default desse tipo**. Por exemplo:

```
int[] seuArray = new int[3];
seuArray[0] = 1;
seuArray[1] = 2;
seuArray[2] = 3;

Array.Clear(seuArray, 0, 1);

foreach (var x in arr) {
    Console.Write(x);
}
```

> Resultado: `023`

Sendo:

- `seuArray`: o array em questão
- `0`: A partir de qual posição deseja "limpar"
- `1`: Quantas posições deseja limpar

---

Para sobrescrever as demais posições basta fazer:

```
seuArray[1] = 5;
seuArray[2] = 6;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var foos = new List<Foo>(array);
foos.RemoveAt(index);
return foos.ToArray();
```

Você pode tentar com método de extensão:

```
public static T[] RemoveAt<T>(this T[] source, int index)
{
    T[] dest = new T[source.Length - 1];
    if( index > 0 )
        Array.Copy(source, 0, dest, 0, index);

    if( index < source.Length - 1 )
        Array.Copy(source, index + 1, dest, index, source.Length - index - 1);

    return dest;
}
```

Usando assim:

```
Foo[] bar = GetFoos();
bar = bar.RemoveAt(2);
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457453/remove-element-of-a-regular-array